# h:commandLink not firing file download action without f:ajax

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, pdf-generation, download

I have an `h:datatable` that contains a column with a link that will call the backing bean and "should" return a PDF document generated.

The column looks like this :

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:datatable>
        ...
        <h:column >
            <h:commandLink action="#{bean.downloadPDF}" target="_blank" >
                <f:param name="value1" value="#{bean.val1}"/>
                <f:param name="value2" value="#{bean.val2}"/>
                <f:param name="value3" value="#{bean.val3}"/>
                <h:graphicImage name="certificate.jpg" library="images"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
        ...
    </h:datatable>
...
</h:form>
```

I have no javascript errors on my page (according to chrome and firebug).  The backing bean looks like this :

```
public void downloadPDF() {
...
File outputPDF = new File(outputFileName);

//Get ready to return pdf to user
BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;
try {
    // Open file.
    input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(outputPDF), 10240);

    //Return PDF to user
    // Init servlet response.
    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(outputPDF.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + pdfName + "\"");
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), 10240);

    // Write file contents to response.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Finalize task.
    output.flush();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

Now, I know my PDF generation works because I can create the custom PDF and save it on the drive.

Then, if I add `<f:ajax/>` to the `h:commandLink` The method is called.  Without that, it reloads the current page without the action method ever being called.

I have tried a few different things... with or without any `f:param`s.  Adding a `String` return value to the `downloadPDF()` function. **EDIT** : Taking away the `target="_blank"` parameter.  Using `actionListener` instead of `action`.  When using `action`, the bean method does not get called, but I get this error message in the `h:messages` : `Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.`.

Cannot get it to call the function.  What I am hoping to get is that when one clicks on the downloadPDF link, it opens a new window and downloads the PDF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT 2 / Solution (temporary)

I have managed to get this working using the attribute `immediate="true"`.  Still havn't found exact field that is giving me the `Conversion Error`, but am assuming is a field in the form that does not need to be submitted for this specific function.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried without target?  Jsf doesn't respond well to such things unless it's directly supported by the tag component.

Comment: @Neil : Same outcome with or without the `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a new feature in jsf 2.0 that I'm unaware of, but I thought action methods had to return a string.  Try changing the signature to return a String, then return null and tell me what happens.

Comment: @Neil I had tried this already.  Tried it again returning a `null` value.  Same results.  If I return, for example, `index` it doesn't make any difference.  Actually, even if I try logging something from that method, it deosn't even get called.  JSF never makes it to the backing bean.

Comment: Yet it gets called with `<f:ajax/>`, strange.  Even without ajax, it should call the method at least.  Have you tried using an actionListener rather than an action?

Comment: @Neil Same thing with the `actionListner`.  Only works with `f:ajax`.  I did notice tho that when I've added a `<f:messages>` tag on the page, I get `Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.`  Not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: @blo0p3r since it is failing conversion it will not call action method as invoke application phase comes after conversion phase, try finding out what is causing conversion to fail, once resolved and no validation errors it will call the action method.

Comment: @gbagga I'm trying to find the value that is trying to be converted and am not being lucky.  Any way to easily pinpoint the value that is trying to be converted?

Comment: That's another problem entirely, but if it doesn't already exist on stackoverflow, create one.  Though first place I'd look [is here](http://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enIT432IT432&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Conversion+Error+setting+value+''+for+'null+Converter%22+messages#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enIT432IT432&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Conversion+Error+setting+value+''+for+'null+Converter%22&oq=%22Conversion+Error+setting+value+''+for+'null+Converter&fp=549d36ac1f5f45be).

Comment: @blo0p3r not sure but check [here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) if that helps..

Comment: You can also check, if the problem is caused by a bug: [http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2345](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic associated with the question was good.  The issue was with other items within the form that were staying null.  As with the **Edit 2**, adding the `immediate="true"` made it so that the fields I needed alone were sent to the servlet.

**Lesson learned**

When submitting part of a form in JSF, make sure only the fields you need are being submitted.  Especially in large forms and integrating ajax with sub sections of the form.